# Pass v-model value from one component to template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I am new in Vue.js and recently, I faced a problem that I should pass a value to the v-model of a template in main.js.
I have the next template :

In main.js

```
  Vue.component("app-input", {
  template: ` 
   <b-row class="my-1 key">
      <b-col sm="5" class="text_aln_rht">
        <label>{{labelName}}</label>
     </b-col>
     <b-col sm="7">
      <b-form-input 
        size="sm"
        v-model="val"
      ></b-form-input>
    </b-col>
  </b-row>
    `,
 props: {
   labelName: String,
   val: String
 },
  methods: {
 }
});
```

This is code from the component

example.vue

```
    <app-input id="MF" name="TYPE_U32" labelName="test" val="Text"></app-input>
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to `$emit` the event with the value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind your prop value like below

```
<app-input id="MF" name="TYPE_U32" :labelName="test" :val="Text"></app-input>
```

If your prop value is not data ( just string ) , use `single squote`

```
<app-input id="MF" name="TYPE_U32" :labelName="'test'" :val="'Text'"></app-input>
```